# Is there a way i can add a class or id to a form generated with UserCreationForm in CreateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, modelform, django-2.1

despite of the hours of struggle i am unable to bootstrap a django form created with UserCreationForm. i want to add bootstrap classes to the  tag but due to my poor knowledge of django class based views i am unable to have a workaround.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

views.py

```
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'age', 'height', 'avatar', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password2'].label = "Confirm Password"
```

Current Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCuHV.png)

Output I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdGd8.jpg)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Django crispy forms. A good package to customize the rendering of django forms. It hast specific tools to render forms using bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 2):

So, I am posting an answer to my own question so that someone looking for that same thing will find the solution in one place. What exactly I was looking for is;

forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'age', 'height', 'avatar', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name',
                                                                'class': 'form-control',
                                                                }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last Name',
                                                                'class': 'form-control',
                                                                }))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email',
                                                                'class': 'form-control mb-4',
                                                                }))
    age = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Age',
                                                                'class': 'form-control',
                                                                }))
    height = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Height(cm)',
                                                                'class': 'form-control',
                                                                }))
    avatar = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Avatar',
                                                                'class': 'form-control  mb-4',
                                                                }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password',
                                                                'class': 'form-control mb-4',
                                                                }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password',
                                                                'class': 'form-control mb-4',
                                                                }))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password2'].label = "Confirm Password"
```

views.py

```
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'
```

accounts/register.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    SignUp
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div style="margin: 75px 0px 0px 0px; background: rgb(87,77,255);
background: linear-gradient(276deg, rgba(87,77,255,0.8830882694874825) 24%, rgba(7,96,255,0.5385504543614321) 77%);" class="bg_cover">
        <form class="text-center col-md-5" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p class="h4 mb-4">SignUp</p>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form.first_name }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form.last_name }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form.email }}
            <div class="form-row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form.age }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ form.height }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form.avatar }}
            {{ form.password1 }}
            {{ form.password2 }}
            <button class="btn-block btn btn-primary my-4" type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4iVu.png)

You can subclass the UserCreationFrom as i did in the CustomUserCreationForm class, then all you have to do is add your desired attributes(bootstrap class names, id's etc) to the form fields you want to modify(beautify). Speaking of "accounts/register.html" written in the SignUp view, i am explicitly telling the django where to find the template. In the template you can render the entire form by `{{ form.as_p }}` or render individual fields as i did in the template!

**Hopefully, my answer would save you from headache i went through to find that!**

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/13/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-forms-with-django.html

or 
https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html

And also when you are rendering your field in your template, For example
{% bootstrap_field form.myfield form_group_class='custom-class-name' %}

You can add a custom class like so. and it 'll show up as a class in your HTML when you inspect so you can use it for your CSS